# Reactjs Tabs switch

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to switch tab by click from a button within the content. Added a button within the content on click switch to another tab.

```js
<Tabs>
   <Tab label="Tab1"> Content <button>Tab2</button></Tab>
   <Tab label="Tab2"> Content <button>Tab1</button></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

I have shown the code I am using in the below link

[code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sound-znvgz5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-tabs` module.
To implement this using the module, you need to use `selectedIndex` and `onSelect` props in `Tabs` component.

For example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from "react-tabs";
import "react-tabs/style/react-tabs.css";

const App = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);
  const switchTab = (index) => {
    setSelectedTab(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs selectedIndex={selectedTab} onSelect={setSelectedTab}>
        <TabList>
          <Tab>Tab1</Tab>
          <Tab>Tab2</Tab>
        </TabList>

        <TabPanel>
          Content
          <button onClick={() => switchTab(1)}>Tab2</button>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel>
          Content
          <button onClick={() => switchTab(0)}>Tab1</button>
        </TabPanel>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```